# What should I report to report progress in the backgroundworker DoWork event?

Tags: c#

This is the code:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            while (true)
            {

                if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (tempCpuValue >= (float?)nud1.Value || tempGpuValue >= (float?)nud1.Value)
                    {
                        soundPlay = true;
                        blinking_label();
                        NudgeMe();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        soundPlay = false;
                        stop_alarm = true;

                    }
                    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(
                }
            }
        }
```

What should i put or use here: `backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress`(
I dont have any progress bar or something. How should i do it ?

Before that the DoWork event was like this:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            while (true)
            {

                if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (tempCpuValue >= (float?)nud1.Value || tempGpuValue >= (float?)nud1.Value)
                    {
                        soundPlay = true;
                        blinking_label();
                        NudgeMe();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        soundPlay = false;
                        stop_alarm = true;

                    }
                    cpuView();
                    gpuView();
                    //Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        }
```

Where inside cpuView() i have:

```
this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                                {
                                    data = new List<string>();
                                    data.Add("Gpu Temeprature --- " + sensor.Value.ToString());
                                    listBox1.DataSource = null;
                                    listBox1.DataSource = data;
                                    listBox1.Invalidate();
                                }));
```

So i thought that the proper way was to use a progrees report and in the progress report event to use this listBox updates . Instead of calling the cpuView and gpuView in the DoWork event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    blinking_label();
```

You cannot blink a label from a background worker.  So it is a good idea to use ReportProgress() to run the code that blinks the label.  The method isn't only useful to report progress, it has a generic capability of running code on the UI thread.

You do need to do something to avoid blinking and nudging over and over again, sleeping for a while for example.  You cannot afford to leave that Sleep() call commented out.  This code is a very strong candidate for a Timer's Elapsed event handler instead of a worker.  That will also ensure that you use the threadpool thread that's used to run this code much more efficiently.  Then use Control.BeginInvoke() to run the code on the UI thread.

Furthermore, since obtaining the cpu temperature should be very cheap, you most likely have no need for a threadpool thread at all.  Which permits using a regular winforms Timer, now everything becomes simple.

Comment: Hans then the better way to work it out is to use a simple Timer ? Then i will do it this way.

Comment: I will remove the backgroundworker at all and instead will use just a simple timer right ?